# How to restore nuget packages referenced by PCL (with project.json) on TFS 2013 Build Server

Tags: tfs, msbuild, nuget, tfsbuild

### What I Need

I'm trying to build PCL library (with project.json) on TFS 2013 Build Server with VS2015 Update1 installed.

### What's the problem

Nuget packages (Mirosoft.NETCore and Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility) for the PCL library are not restored.

I'm getting errors like

```
 Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs (9): The type or namespace name 'AssemblyTitle' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
 Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs (17): Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported
 Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs (29): Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported
 Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs (30): Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported

 C:\Users\MHABLDSvc\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETPortable,Version=v5.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs (4): Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported
 C:\Users\MHABLDSvc\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETPortable,Version=v5.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs (4): The type or namespace name 'FrameworkDisplayName' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
 C:\Users\MHABLDSvc\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETPortable,Version=v5.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs (4): Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported
```

### What I've tried:

The first attempt was to enable Automatic Package Restore in $slnDir$.nuget\nuget.exe. This works in visual studio, but not during the TFS Build.

So I changed the TFS build definition to build my **build.proj** instead of .sln file.

It restores nuget packages for .NET 4.6 class library, but not for my PCL library

build.proj

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0"
         DefaultTargets="Build"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <Target Name="UnsetReadonly">
    <Exec Command="attrib -r &quot;$(SourceDir)*.*&quot; /s"/>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="RestorePackages" DependsOnTargets="UnsetReadonly">
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Nuget-Publishing\NuGet.exe&quot; restore &quot;%(Solution.Identity)&quot;" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Clean">
    <MSBuild Targets="Clean" 
             Projects="@(Solution)" />
  </Target>



  <Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="RestorePackages">

    <MSBuild Targets="Build" 
             Projects="@(Solution)"
             UseResultsCache="True" StopOnFirstFailure="true" Properties="Verbosity=Minimal"  />

  </Target>    
</Project>
```

`nuget.exe restore` says: All packages listed in packages.config are already installed. However, my problem are packaged from project.json

Comment: What's the output of nuget restore? does it work from cmd? are you using the latest version of nuget.exe?

Comment: I'm using nuge.exe 3.3.0. from the command line it gives the same result: All packages listed in packages.config are already installed

Comment: It seems to work with latest 3.4.0 beta!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved in NuGet 3.4.

Related issue:

[Cannot install NuGet package depending on Microsoft.NETCore into .NET Framework 4.6 console application project #1883](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1883)

Not sure but this [commit](https://github.com/dsplaisted/msbuild/commit/3595c32c328c8687597cf1b96b7dd7b179fe1cc3) on `project.json` might have fixed it.